# Can you check if 4 out of 7 variables are the same?

Tags: python

I have 7 different variables that range from 1-4 (randomly), and I need 4 of them to match in order to break the `while` loop. I was thinking of using something like an `if` statement that checks all the variables but not sure how to make it register that only 4 of them need to be the same, not all of them.

This is how I started it:

```
if (trial_number_a == trial_number_b == 
    trial_number_c == trial_number_d ==
    trial_number_e == trial_number_f ==
    trial_number_g):
    break
```

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if you could use a dictionary and see if the max value from all of the keys is greater than 4. As in. keys are 1,2,3,4 and values are the counts of those keys. Then you take the maximum value of the keys and check if that's greater than 4. Does this solve your question?

Comment: @ananyajoshi that’s why we use a Counter here; a Counter is basically a dictionary with extra functionality to make counting things easy.

Answer (score 6):

Put all values into a [`Counter` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), then test the largest count:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter((
    trial_number_a, trial_number_b, trial_number_c,
    trial_number_d, trial_number_e, trial_number_f,
    trial_number_g
))
if counts.most_common(1)[0][1] >= 4:
    # 4 or more variable have the same value.
```

Counters are *multisets*; they track values, and their counts. A regular set doesn’t work here as it would not tell you how many values were equal to each other, only that there were repeated values.

The above code uses the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to get a list with the single most common value and its count as a tuple.

Having to index into a list then into a tuple is a bit tedious so you could use variable unpacking:

```
counts = ... # elided for brevity
[(_, topcount)] = counts.most_common(1) # extract value from nested tuple
if topcount >= 4:
    # 4 or more variables have the same value.
```

The `_` variable name here is a convention to say we are going to ignore whatever assigned to it.

By the way, rather than use 7 separate variables, consider using a list or dictionary to hold those 7 values; e.g. to create a dictionary with the letters a-g as keys and starting value 0:

```
trial_numbers = dict.fromkeys("abcdefg", 0)
```

After which you can update each by their key (`trial_numbers["a"] += 42`), and, more importantly, refer to all their values trivially (e.g. `Counter(trial_numbers.values())`).

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> trial_numbers = {
...     'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 1, 'd': 3,
...     'e': 1, 'f': 2, 'g': 1,
... }
>>> counts = Counter(trial_numbers.values())
>>> counts
Counter({1: 4, 4: 1, 3: 1, 2: 1})
>>> counts.most_common(1)  # which value is the most common
[(1, 4)]
>>> [(_, topcount)] = counts.most_common(1)
>>> topcount
4
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, your code is probably much simpler using a list to hold the trial numbers, instead of a bunch of separate variables.

You can use the built-in `collections.Counter` to find out how many times each value appears among the trials, and then see which value is most common, and then see if it appeared at least 4 times:

```
from collections import Counter

# Notice the extra brackets to put the trials into a list first.
histogram = Counter([
    trial_number_a, trial_number_b, trial_number_c, trial_number_d,
    trial_number_e, trial_number_f, trial_number_g
])
if histogram.most_common()[0][1] >= 4:
    # most_common() gave us a list of pairs of (value, frequency).
    # the [0] element is the most common one, and the [1] of that pair
    # is the number of times it showed up. We don't care what the value was.
    pass # logic goes here
```

Comment: Do tell `most_common()` to return just one value! If you pass in a number *n* only the top *n* entries are returned. The method can then use an optimised implementation to do that rather than use a full sort.

Comment: For 7 items you'd not see much difference, constant costs will dominate. The implementation uses `max()` when asking for N=1 item (so takes O(K) time for a counter of size K), a maxheap (heapq) for  any other N that's still smaller than the size K (taking O(K log(N)) time), and for K == N (or no argument given) then sorting is used (which takes O(K log(K)) time). If you were to benchmark this with, say, 1 million entries, you'd see *big* differences between using `.most_common()` and `.most_common(1)`.

Comment: Here's a quick benchmark running on Repl.it (slooooow, but shows the time differences nicely, using a counter with 100k items): https://repl.it/@mjpieters/counterbench

Answer (score 1):

You can create Set of all variable and check length to see how many duplicate variables were removed to create Set.

```
list_of_var = [trial_number_a, trial_number_b, trial_number_c, trial_number_d, trial_number_e, trial_number_f, trial_number_g]
set_of_var = set(list_of_var)
num_of_unique_vars = len(set_of_var)

if num_of_unique_vars == 4:
    break
```

Comment: What about when the values are 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4?

Comment: Not quite. OP doesn't want the number of unique values, but the number of times that the most common value showed up (since the question is whether *some* value showed up *at least* a certain number of times).

Comment: @oldwooki Ahh, nice catch. Didn't think that :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use a list to store the values instead of individual variables.  But if you're going to use variables, you can determine if at least 4 of them are the same using the Counter class from the collections module:

```
same = Counter((trial_number_a, trial_number_b, trial_number_c,
                trial_number_d, trial_number_e, trial_number_f,
                trial_number_g))
if any( count>=4 for count in same.values() ):
    break
```

Without using libraries, you could also leverage the fact that, for a list of 7 sorted values, when there are at least 4 identical values, the middle point of the sorted list will be the repeated value:

```
values = sorted((trial_number_a,trial_number_b, 
                 trial_number_c,trial_number_d,
                 trial_number_e,trial_number_f,
                 trial_number_g))
if values.count(values[3]) >= 4
    break
```

An even simpler (albeit less efficient) approach would be to simply place the values in a list and check if any of them are present 4 or more times in the list:

```
values = [trial_number_a,trial_number_b, 
          trial_number_c,trial_number_d,
          trial_number_e,trial_number_f,
          trial_number_g]
if any(values.count(v)>=4 for v in values):
    break
```